# Why jQuery.parseJSON does not parse this valid JSON document in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firefox

Server returns this JSON document:

```
{
"username-found": true,
"question-required": true
}
```

Which successfully passes JSONLint's validity check.

In web browser:

```
$.post('my_url', {"post":"data"}, function(data) {
  data = $.parseJSON(data);
});
```

The code runs and successfully parses the JSON document in Opera 12 browser, however in Firefox 16, JavaScript error occurs and says "not well-formed".

JQuery is of version 1.7.2.

I cannot see what I did wrong there, do you know?

Edit:

Does it have anything to do with the way server returns the JSON? Here it is:

```
return new StreamingResolution("text", new StringReader(json.toString()));
```

uggestion, I might have found the cause. When I did `alert(data)`, Firefox tells me that `data` is an object, Opera tells me that `data` is the JSON string.

Comment: Is there any weird characters in the response?

Comment: Works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/KzyaS/ Firefox 16.0.1 on Linux.

Comment: If you have a look at http://jsonlint.com/ this parses without a problem. I guess there is another problem, it's not the JSON you posted.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, you can change the dataType on the client or send the correct MIME from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 (Client) - Set DataType in jQuery Request**

I think the internals are a bit different in that specific browser version (because jQuery tries to detect the dataType automatically and is doing the parsing internally in the case of a JSON response) and JSON is automatically encoded in FF and not in Opera?

Try to add the dataType so jQuery will handle this (I would prefer that):

```
$.post('my_url', {"post":"data"}, function(data) {
    // data should be an json object here
}, 'json');
```

It's just a guess.

**OR Solution 2 (Server) - Send MIME type**

You could also send a correct MIME type from the server so you don't have to set the dataType on the client. Its up to you but I think that would be the correct solution.

Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) answer it should be `application/json`.

**Reference**

How is the dataType detected automatically in jQuery?

> Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html) The type of
>   data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified,
>   jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an
>   XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript
>   object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will
>   be returned as a string).

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: That's not how you pass the data type, you have to pass it as fourth argument to the function. The second argument is only the data that is supposed to be sent to the server. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Uups, thank you, its a $.post and not an $.ajax call, you're right! I change it.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is likely the cause of my problem. Firefox appears to automatically parses `data` into object, however Opera leaves it in string form.

Comment: I don't know what exactly jQuery is doing when it has to detect the dataType so always when you have problems just tell jQuery what you will get from the server and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm getting JSON text using Google's GSON in the form of string. This text parsed properly on **JSONLint** where as it is getting failed when I do `$.parseJSON('<%= formattedGSONText %>')` What care should be taken for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the `data` object directly ..

No need to use `$.parseJSON();`

Comment: Thank you, I just figured that out. Opera leaves `data` in string, however Firefox automatically parses it. Which browser is more correct in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You also have a $.getJSON shortcut method in jQuery. Maybe jQuery automatically uses the best configuration for this case and maybe start working

[Here is the $.getJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)